# My Schengen visa will expire soon - how soon is a new one required?

Tags: visas, schengen, netherlands, schengen-visas

I'm planning to visit the Netherlands on June 17 for 1 week and the
expiration date of my visa is July 3.  Is it ok or do I need to apply for a new one ?

Answer (score 4):

Your Schengen visa has a **validity period**, a **duration of stay**, and a **number of entries**. You can use it during the entire validity period if you have duration and entries left.

Comment: And comply with the 90/180 rule.